# MVC Razor CheckBoxFor() not displaying property contents / value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Pretty simple..or so I thought. This is a plugin page in NopCommerce but I don't think that is at play here.

My Models:

```
public class CheckBoxModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}


public partial class ContactUsModel : BaseNopModel
{
   [AllowHtml]
   [DisplayName("Case Type")]
   public List<CheckBoxModel> CaseType { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller for a quick check to see if form is displaying correctly:

```
var model = new ContactUsModel
{
   CaseType = new List<CheckBoxModel>()
   {
      new CheckBoxModel() { Name="Civil Tax", Checked=false },
      new CheckBoxModel() { Name="Criminal Tax", Checked=false },
      new CheckBoxModel() { Name="Other Tax", Checked=false }
   }
}
```

My razor:

```
<div class="inputs">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseType)
   @for(int i = 0; i < Model.CaseType.Count; i++)
   {
      @Html.LabelFor(lbl => lbl.CaseType[i].Name)
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(chk => chk.CaseType[i].Checked)
   }
</div>
```

HTML:

```
Case Type:    Name []      Name[]     Name[]
```

What am I missing to get the actual name assigned in the controller to show??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="inputs">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaseType)
   @for(int i = 0; i < Model.CaseType.Count; i++)
   {
      @Html.DisplayFor(lbl => lbl.CaseType[i].Name)
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(chk => chk.CaseType[i].Checked)
   }
</div>
```

LabelFor will print the name of the property, which is not what you're looking for.  DisplayFor will print the value.

Comment: What you really want is `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CaseType[i].Checked, Model[i].Name)` so that you create a label associated with the checkbox (and displays the value of the associated `Name` property). And you should replace `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CaseType)` with `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CaseType)` since you do not have a control named `CaseType` so a `<label>` makes no sense.